# Ending the while loop using Cancel button or X button

Tags: java, swing, loops

I need help with ending the loop when the user clicks the X button or CANCEL button then click the OK or X of the message dialog box.

This is my code:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
public class SimpleCalculator1 
{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int error1, error2;
        JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
           JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
           JTextField field3 = new JTextField();
        Object[] message = 
            {
            "Enter first integer:", field1,
            "Input second integer:", field2,
            "Choose the operation to be used\nAddition(+)\nSubtraction(-)\nMultiplication(*)\nDivision(/):", field3,
            };
        int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "SimpleCalculator", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

        while(true)
        {
            if(option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
            {
                String value1 = field1.getText();
                String value2 = field2.getText();         
                String operation = field3.getText();

                try
                {
                   int num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                   int num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException ne)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Invalid! Please input an integer","Error", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); //When I press ok, I need help to bring me back to input entries
                }

                switch(operation = field3.getText())
                {
                   case "+":
                    {
                        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                        int result = num1+num2;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The sum is: "+result); 
                        break;
                    }
                case "-":
                    {
                        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                        int result = num1-num2;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The difference is: "+result); 
                        break;
                    }
                 case "*":
                    {
                        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                        int result = num1*num2;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The product is: "+result); 
                        break;
                    }
                case "/":
                    {
                        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                        double result = (double)num1/num2;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The quotient is: "+result); 
                        break;
                    }

                default: 
                    error1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Invalid operation, please try again","Error",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); //I need help here for creating a loop that will take me back to the beginning.
                }
                option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "SimpleCalculator", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

            }
            else if (option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you for using our program!");

            else 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you for using our program!");    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `Break` to exit loop if the user clicked close or cancel

```
while(true)
{
    if(option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
    {
        String value1 = field1.getText();


        String value2 = field2.getText();


        String operation = field3.getText();

        try
        {
           int num1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
           int num2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ne)
        {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Invalid! Please input an integer","Error", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); //When I press ok, I need help to bring me back to input entries
        }
    }
    else if(option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION || option == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoshuaEnriquez, I suggest ["accepting"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of the right answers. :)

Comment: I did accepted Clyme's answers, I just show gratitude for answering my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about java but simple idea is you need to place a variable initialized with true value in global place, and in each iteration check if that variable is still true, if the variable is false then stop/break/return the loop.
and you can set the value of that variable by button using onclick event like onclick="variable=false;"

Answer (score 0):

just create a boolean before you enter the loop:

```
boolean shouldExit = false;
while (!shouldExit) ...
```

and if the user wants to cancel the program you can set the boolean to true:

```
if (option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
shouldExit = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I know how to cancel an infinite loop when a user clicks a certain button on JOptionPane

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped you :D